# How does std::vector's copy constructor operate?

Tags: c++, string, vector, std

How does a `std::vector<std::string>` initialize its self when the following code is invoked

```
std::vector<std::string> original;
std::vector<std::string> newVector = original;
```

It would seem as if the copy constructor would be invoked on `std::vector<std::string> new` during `newVector = original`, but how are the `std::string`'s brought over inside of the `orginal`? Are they copies or new `std::string`'s? So is the memory in `newVector[0]` the same as `original[0]`.

The reason I ask is say I do the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> globalVector;

void Initialize() {
    globalVector.push_back("One");
    globalVector.push_back("Two");
}

void DoStuff() {
    vector<string> t = globalVector;
}

int main(void) {
    Initialize();
    DoStuff();
}
```

`t` will fall out of scope of `DoStuff` (on a non optimized build), but if it `t` is just filled with pointers to the `std::string`'s in `globalVector`, might the destructor be called and the memory used in `std::string` deleted, there for making `globalVector[0]` filled with garbage `std::string`'s after `DoStuff` is called?

A nut shell, I am basically asking, when `std::vector`'s copy constructor is called, how are the elements inside copied?

Comment: Pretty sure this was just an example but in your first code block, `std::vector<std::string> new = original;`, that `new` is not a legal variable name.  I'm sure you know that it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: @ChrisA.: You are right, it was just test code

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`std::vector` and most other standard library containers store elements by value. The elements are copied on insertion or when the container is copied. `std::string` also maintains its own copy of the data, as far as your usage of it is concerned.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  You are right, as far as the container's user is concerned.  However, as you most likely know, Stroustrup reminds us that some containers, like `std::string`, may copy data *lazily,* meaning that the actual copy action might not internally be done until one of the strings (the original or the copy) is used in a manner that requires it to have been done.  At any rate, I think that the answerer is technically right to say *most* in this instance, especially in the manner in which he has qualified his usage.

Comment: @thb `std::string` is only sort-of a container, it is restricted to "char-like types" (i.e. it cannot store other containers), and copy-on-write is deprecated now that multithreading is prevalent.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  I did not know and had not thought of your multithreading point.  Of course you are also right about the "sort-of a container."  The correction is accepted with thanks.

Comment: So just to be clear on terminology, `newVector[0] is not the same memory as original[0]` and it the copy constructor is called for the new string?

Comment: @chadb: Yes, they are independent containers containing independent elements. That just so happen to have the semantically identical contents.