# vector push_back calling copy_constructor more than once?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am a bit confused with the way vector push_back behaves, with the following snippet I expected the copy constructor to be invoked only twice, but the output suggest otherwise. Is it a vector internal restructuring that results in this behaviour.

Output:

> ```
> Inside default
>
> Inside copy with my_int = 0
>
> Inside copy with my_int = 0
>
> Inside copy with my_int = 1
> ```

```
class Myint
{
private:
    int my_int;
public:
    Myint() : my_int(0) 
    {
        cout << "Inside default " << endl;
    }
    Myint(const Myint& x) : my_int(x.my_int)
    {
        cout << "Inside copy with my_int = " << x.my_int << endl;
    }

    void set(const int &x)
    {
        my_int = x;
    }
}

vector<Myint> myints;
Myint x;

myints.push_back(x);
x.set(1);
myints.push_back(x);
```

Comment: Related question with `emplace_back`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948442/emplace-back-does-not-behave-as-expected/23948499?s=8|0.0000#23948499

Comment: Depends on the object, if you define in addition a move constructor it will move instead of copy, which is more efficient. See also [c++ - How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What happens:

1. `x` is inserted via `push_back`. One copy occurs: The newly created element is initialized with the argument. `my_int` is taken over as zero because `x`s default constructor initialized it so.
2. The second element is `push_back`'d; The vector needs to reallocate the memory since [the internal capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) was reached.
    As no move constructor is implicitly defined for `Myint`<sup>1</sup> the copy constructor is chosen; The first element is copied into the newly allocated memory (its `my_int` is still zero... so the copy constructor shows `my_int` as `0` again) and then `x` is copied to initialize the second element (as with the first in step 1.). This time `x` has `my_int` set to one and that's what the output of the copy constructor tells us.

So the total amount of calls is three. This might vary from one implementation to another as the initial capacity might be different. However, two calls are be the minimum.

You can reduce the amount of copies by, in advance, reserving more memory - i.e. higher the vectors capacity so the reallocation becomes unnecessary:

```
myints.reserve(2); // Now two elements can be inserted without reallocation.
```

Furthermore you can elide the copies when inserting as follows:

```
myints.emplace_back(0);
```

This "emplaces" a new element - [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) is a variadic template and can therefore take an arbitrary amount of arguments which it then forwards  - without copies or moves - to the elements constructor.

<sup>1</sup> Because there is a user-declared copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You got it...it was the resizing.  But I'll just point out that if you're doing some bean counting on your constructors, you might be interested in "emplacement":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Myint
{
private:
    int my_int;
public:
    explicit Myint(int value = 0) : my_int(value) 
    {
        cout << "Inside default " << endl;
    }
    Myint(const Myint& x) : my_int(x.my_int)
    {
        cout << "Inside copy with my_int = " << x.my_int << endl;
    }
    Myint(const Myint&& x) noexcept : my_int(x.my_int) {
        cout << "Inside move with my_int = " << x.my_int << endl;
    } 
};

int main() {
    vector<Myint> myints;
    myints.reserve(2);

    myints.emplace_back(0);
    myints.emplace_back(1);

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

That should give you:

```
Inside default 
Inside default
```

And, due to the [noexcept on the move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)...if you delete the `reserve` you'd get a move, not a copy:

```
Inside default 
Inside default 
Inside move with my_int = 0
```

There's no real advantage with this datatype of a move over a copy.  But semantically it could be a big difference if your data type was more "heavy weight" and had a way of "moving" its members that was more like transferring ownership of some pointer to a large data structure.

Answer (score 3):

When the size of the vector is increased with the second `push_back`, the existing contents of the vector must be copied to a new buffer. To verify, output `myints.capacity()` after the first `push_back`, it should be `1`.

Comment: Unrelated: Why does [this same example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6284e04a0389e29) give output `0 1 0` instead of `0 0 1` in the OP's code?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it's possible that the implementation copies the `push_back` element to the new buffer before it copies the old buffer.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how much memory was reserved to an object of type `std::vector`. It seems that when `push_back` was first executed there was allocated memory only for one element. When the second time `push_back` was called the memory was reallocated to reserve memory for the second element. In this case the element that is already in the vector is copied in the new place. And then the second element is also added.

You could reserve enough memory yourself that to escape the second call of the copy constructor:

```
vector<Myint> myints;
myints.reserve( 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in assuming the additional invocation of the copy constructor comes from internal restructuring of the vector.

See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368636/3708904

Or this answer for the reason why copy construction is necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166959/3708904