# Copy constructor called too many times

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int counter = 0;
struct vecobj
{
   int elem;
   vecobj(){ }
   vecobj(const vecobj& rhs)
   {
    counter++;
    elem = rhs.elem;
    
    
   }
};

vector<vecobj> objvec;

int main()
{
    vecobj obj1;
    obj1.elem = 1;
    objvec.push_back(obj1);
    objvec.push_back(obj1);
    objvec.push_back(obj1);
    std::cout <<"copy constructor called "<< counter <<" times\n";
}
```

My question is that when I push an object into the vector `objvec`, I get the copy constructor called 6 times. While I have pushed only three times. I have verified this with the debugger. I am using visual studio 2017 Community Edition. Is it a bug with STL?
I think a related question does not address the problem fully.
No where is it documented that the vector memory has to be reserved before pushing onto it.The pushing of object calling the copy constructor too many (fibonacci(n)) times can have unintended side effects. I think STL code needs
to be changed for the same.

Comment: No it's normal. Count the places where your object has to be copied. In particular think about how push_back may do its job ^^

Comment: if i push 4 times then it calls the copy constructor fibonacci(4) = 10 times and so on

Comment: No I have not turned on any optimizations. C++ standard must be > C++11.

Comment: Reserving memory violates the dynamic allocation principle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vector push\_back calling copy\_constructor more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740523/vector-push-back-calling-copy-constructor-more-than-once)

Comment: What I mean is, you usually need to turn on the optimizer so it elide unnecessary copies (but it isn't the case this time)

Answer (score 4):

Normally `std::vector` implementation have a **capacity** and a **size** variables. To track the current **capacity** means maximum number of elements that can be created without requesting a bigger heap block. 1size1 tracks the current size of `std::vector`.

When we `push_back` an element and size becomes greater than **capacity** then program will ask for new heap and copy all the elements to new location.

**Capacity** increases in power of 2. like initially space for 1 object/variable will be allocated, if application will need more then space for 2 objects/variables will be allocated, then for 4 and so on.

1. Initially first copy happens when you `push_back` first element. (1 Copy)
2. When you `push_back` second element then a new memory is allocated and the new element as well as the already `push_back`ed element is copied to new location. (2 Copy)
3. Similarly third time three copies will happen.

All of this is implementation dependent. Standard don't impose that `std::vector` should behave like this only.

To save the copies you can `reserve` the enough memory before you make any `push_back` call.

Comment: small nitpick: It is not necessarily a factor of 2. A factor of 3 would be conforming as well. Actually any factor is fine to guarantee armortized constant complexity for `push_back` (which is the reason for needing to have a reallocation strategy that not just allocates enough for the current size)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, You are right its implementation dependent . I have added that line in answer.

Comment: …and a good example is MSVC, which does not use factors of 2.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `Actually any factor is fine` Are you sure? Surely any factor less than or equal to 1 won't be fine :)

Comment: @eerorika always glad to see that I am not the only nitpicker :P. "Any constant integer greater or equal than 2" is less wrong I believe ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I've read MSVC uses 1.5. I've pondered occasionally, but never bothered to do the math to prove or disprove whether any or all factors in the interval ]1, 2[ achieve amortised constant complexity.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Feel Free to update the answer if you think any additional info can help the seekers.

Comment: @eerorika oh well, msvc not using 2 was new to me. 1.5 is another surprise I have to admit. I remeber an article that discussed the requirement of amortized constant push_back and the resulting requirement on the factor in all glory details. What I kept in memory was a simple "anything >= 2 is fine", I suppose that was wrong. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4):

You already have the trivial 3 copies here:

```
objvec.push_back(obj1);
objvec.push_back(obj1);
objvec.push_back(obj1);
```

Then you might check `capacity` (depend of implementation), [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b89db1e91350eb89) I have:

```
std::cout << "capacity: " << objvec.capacity() << std::endl; // 0
objvec.push_back(obj1);
std::cout << "capacity: " << objvec.capacity() << std::endl; // 1
objvec.push_back(obj1);
std::cout << "capacity: " << objvec.capacity() << std::endl; // 2
objvec.push_back(obj1);
std::cout << "capacity: " << objvec.capacity() << std::endl; // 4
```

Each time capacity changes, reallocation happens, and we have to transfer data from old buffer to the new one. so copy (or move).

You might reduce copy by using correct capacity from the beginning:

```
vecobj obj1;
obj1.elem = 1;

objvec.reserve(3);
objvec.push_back(obj1);
objvec.push_back(obj1);
objvec.push_back(obj1);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c5e1d1b065e8709)

Answer (score 0):

Lets put moves aside (your elements cannot be moved), then `push_back` copies at least one element to insert it into the vector. If the vectors capacity is not enough to hold the additional element, then the vector has to resize. While doing that it copies all elements. Typical resize strategies allocate space for elements by factors of two. So this is possibly what happens:

```
 vecobj obj1;               // size 0 capacity 0
obj1.elem = 1;
objvec.push_back(obj1);     // size 1 capacity 1   -> 1 copy to insert
objvec.push_back(obj1);     // size 2 capacity 2   -> 1 copy to insert 1 to reallocate
objvec.push_back(obj1);     // size 3 capacity 4   -> 1 copy to insert 2 to reallocate
```

Which makes a total of 6 copies.

Comment: I am aware of rule of three (if i am correct it is copy ctor, destructor and assignment operator) and not rule of five

Comment: My comment on unwanted side effects got deleted!!?

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda did you comment on the wrong answer? I am not mentioning the rule of 3/5

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda fyi comments can get deleted at any time, but it only happens when there is a reason to be deleted.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda you made a comment about "unwanted sideeffect" on a different answer

Comment: Reserving memory before hand violates the dynamic allocation principle.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda you wrote that before, but I don't understand. What is the "dynamic allocation principle" ? Why is it violated when a vector is resized?

Comment: I am a new user. Please bear with me. Permanent comments for all esteemed members to see is preferable.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda you may wish to have permanent comments, but comments are not permanent on SO.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers from all esteemed members. This looks like a bug to me in STL. Please read my revised post also.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda Frankly, you seem to ignore all the answers that try to explain that seeing more copies than the number of `push_back`s can be expected for your code. This is not a bug, but you misunderstand something. Please do not alter your question substantially after you recieved answers

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda If you explain why you think this would be a bug, maybe we can explain more.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda well ok, I read your edit on the question again. The thing is just that you expect something that is not how `std::vector` works. If a vector resizes it may need to reallocate and that may require to copy elements. Thats just how it is. If that is not what you want then don't use a vector

Comment: I will try to explain the side effects part with changes to my code. which results in not standard but unexpected behavior.

Comment: @ramesh_deekonda this is well documented standard behavior.

Comment: I have earlier faced problem with stl and copy constructors and I had to write my own vector class.  spectras and user202729 and Nicolaus dusart thanks for your replies too.